# Java Play 2.5.x JavaCache - How to get the current cache instance?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, playframework-2.5

I've followed the example at https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaCache and I can successfully access the cache, but I only seem to be able to do this from a controller method.  Specifically:

```
@Inject
public OverviewController(CacheApi cache) { this.lookupCache = cache; }
```

From the controller actions, I can then interrogate the cache as needed via lookupCache.

My problem is that I need this functionality a few layers deeper in the application, and I'd really like to prevent passing a reference to lookupCache through several other constructors.

The documentation seems to suggest the capability of adding this injection on any "component", which would give me what I want, but if I try the same injection on some other class:

```
public class DropDownCache {
    private CacheApi lookupCache;
    @Inject
    public DropDownCache(CacheApi cache) { this.lookupCache = cache; }
}
```

...then any time I instantiate DropDownCache, I have to supply the CacheApi instance.  This tells me that the controller is magically being instantiated with this reference, I just don't know how to access it.

Does anyone have any pointers on where the controllers get their instance of CacheApi from?

Comment: Are you able to inject `DropDownCache` into your controller?

Comment: @MatthiasEckhart, yes but I'm I'm trying to use this cache in a different layer of the application.  I've only been able to use this in the controllers which means I'd have to pass references into the other layers needed.  The documentation suggests I should be able to use this cache anywhere within the play app though.

Comment: Is your `DropDownCache` a Guice bean, unless your class is a guice bean none of the `@Inject` will work. In case of Controller, the controller is a guice bean and it is instantiated by the guice.